# Failing to start shard in ElasticSearch IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException "sending failed"

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I'm getting this error, in my ES log  I'm using three nodes.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
[2014-09-08 13:53:56,167][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Dancing Destroyer] [events][3] sending failed shard for [events][3], node[RDZy21y7SRep7n6oWT8ogg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [gzj1aHTnQX6XDc0SxkvxDQ], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[events][3] failed recovery]; nested: FlushFailedEngineException[[events][3] Flush failed]; nested: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException; ]]
[2014-09-08 13:53:56,357][WARN ][indices.cluster          ] [Dancing Destroyer] [events][3] failed to start shard
org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException: [events][3] failed recovery
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:185)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.engine.FlushFailedEngineException: [events][3] Flush failed
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.flush(InternalEngine.java:805)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.performRecoveryFinalization(InternalIndexShard.java:726)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:132)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
[2014-09-08 13:53:56,381][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Dancing Destroyer] [events][3] sending failed shard for [events][3], node[RDZy21y7SRep7n6oWT8ogg], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [gzj1aHTnQX6XDc0SxkvxDQ], reason [Failed to start shard, message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[events][3] failed recovery]; nested: FlushFailedEngineException[[events][3] Flush failed]; nested: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException; ]]
```

This means that the status of ES is red and I'm missing nearly 10 million documents.
What does this error mean, so that I'd might be able to recover?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that I had a messed up shard, that needed fixing.
It's a [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) thing, where you tell Lucene to fix the shard.

For Ubuntu, the solution was to go to the `/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib` directory and find out which Lucene core version is was running (running `ls` will show you a file named something  like lucene-core-4.8.1.jar) and then type:

```
java -cp lucene-core-x.x.x.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /var/lib/elasticsearch/<clustername>/nodes/0/indices/<index>/<shard>/index/ -fix
```

Replace the x.x.x with the Lucene core version,  with your clustername, index with the name of the index and of course  with the failing shard number.

**This can potentially give a loss of documents**

But it fixed our issue.

Comment: Do you have any more info on why this happened? Are there any preventative measures you have taken??

Comment: @EricUldall I'm my case my server ran out of disk space, which probably led to ES writing partial data to disk.

Comment: Thanks for this one, you saved some trouble. I made a simple [ruby script](https://gist.github.com/atmosx/54a7e4904d4b36aea3bb) to fix that automatically.

Answer (score 6):

I faced this problem multiple times. As my set up is to read clickstream data (12-20M hits a day), I could not afford data losses.

So this was my solution and it runs beautifully:

**Solution**:

1. Stop elasticsearch from running
2. go to /path/to/my/data/mycluster_name/nodes/0/indices/myindex_name/index
3. delete segments.gen file
4. Start elasticsearch

**Problem Root Cause**

1. Shards fail for various reasons, especially when shards are not able to fulfill Kibana requests.
2. Lucene is not directly connected to this process. So when there are issues, elasticsearch is not able to efficiently pick the shards value from Lucene segments references that are stored in segments.gen
3. Lucene sets this value fresh again in the next run. So elasticsearch is able to reference the values correctly. And the shard issue is resolved.

Comment: [Elastic says this is a "terrible idea"](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/replica-shards-stuck-in-initialization-phase/48448/3).

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi, I met Elastic prod engineers myself and they figured out this solution. Thank you for letting me know though!

Answer (score 2):

Taking hints from [Repox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842934/422842). In Centos 6.5 with the built-in ElasticSearch in logstash provisioned using Chef.

- https://github.com/lusis/chef-logstash (v0.10.0)
- logstash 1.4.2
- ES/logstash working directory eg /opt/logstash/forwarder

`java -cp /opt/logstash/forwarder/vendor/jar/elasticsearch-1.1.1/lib/lucene-core-4.7.2.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex /opt/logstash/forwarder/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/logstash-2014.11.01/3/index/ -fix`

But even with fixing I still see *Failed to start shard, message ... failed to recover shard*. I have to destructively delete using eg `curator delete --older-than 3`.